# Unity Procedural Game Optimization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently developing a 3d dungeon crawler which implements a procedural dungeon generation system which works perfectly fine. However the game is not very performant. I have tried a few optimization tricks I heard like:

- Adding LOD Groups to each room prefab (this works perfectly fine), has impact on fps and batches
- Tried addig static batching, I made every room prefab static and enabled dynamic and static batching in the player settings, however there is no change in the batches count or the saved batches count.
- Tried addind occlusion culling but i cannot bake it before the game, as it's a procedural generated world.
- The room prefabs are low poly rooms and are not even decorated yet, just the floor and walls and torches.

---

I should mention that i am using deffered lightning and I am activating the torch point lights as the players walks in the room. There aren't any baked lights everything is realtime. Every room prefab uses the same metrial and is **not** copied when the room is instantiated.

---

Some screenshots to help you understand better:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

If you need anymore info, please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks you

Comment: Stack overflow is a site focus on programming. Your question need to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to focus on your issue. You may still receive answers from other developers but don't be surprised if your question get downvoted.

Comment: I agree with Hardcore gamer, that being said, one option might be just setting rooms out of sight to inactive

Comment: I have already done that through the lod group setup.

Comment: What is the bottleneck? Isolate each part of your algorithm and benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Might be overkill, but have you thought about making the meshes a subscene / an entity using dots. Then just handle the colliders separately.

Hope that works for you.

If that is still having issues you may consider removing any colliders that are outside of a certain distance from you, and loading them in when you get close.

Comment: I need to mention that i made a very low poly collider (20 poligons) in blender for each room prefab and just assign it to the mesh collider.